# Why my heap implementation in Python is much slower compared to the heapq standard lib?

Tags: python, heap

I'm implementing Min Heap myself, this is my insert func:

```
    def insert(self, new_elem):
        self.elems.append(new_elem)
        cur_pos = len(self.elems) - 1

        while cur_pos > 0:
            par_pos = (cur_pos - 1) // 2
            if self.elems[cur_pos] >= self.elems[par_pos]:
                break
            else:
                self.swap_node(cur_pos, par_pos)
            cur_pos = par_pos
```

I try to insert a list like this:

```
    for i in range(int(3e5), -1, -1):
        min_heap.insert(i)
```

These operations takes 0.73s in my Heap implementation whereas it takes only 0.05s using the heapq lib. I have noticed that heapq is **not** implemented in C. So why is there such a big difference?

Comment: The answer below shows evidence that the assumption "`heapq` is *not* implemented in C" (the reason for the question) is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

> I notice that heapq is not implmented in C

eheh... welll... if you scroll down to the bottom of `heapq.py`:

> ```py
> # If available, use C implementation
> try:
>     from _heapq import *
> except ImportError:
>     pass
> try:
>     from _heapq import _heapreplace_max
> except ImportError:
>     pass
> try:
>     from _heapq import _heapify_max
> except ImportError:
>     pass
> try:
>     from _heapq import _heappop_max
> except ImportError:
>     pass
> ```

Comment: You're right, it's my bad. However, I have commented these lines to use Python implementation, but it still takes only 0.05s.

Comment: @Straw - You may need to delete the `heapq.pyc` compiled byte-code file in order to force it to be recreated with only the Python implementation after you commented out those imports.